# Activate Bitlocker on Windows 11 Home

Tags: windows-11, bitlocker

## Short history

For one of our customers, they have a Windows Surface 8 and upon buying it, they logged in using a Microsoft Account.

This personal account has the same email address as their business office 365 account, but with a different password.

Because of this, office365 occasionally asks for a password or simply stops working for a while. The solution is to sign out of the personal account and convert it to a local account.

When I attempted to do this, Windows warned me that the drive was encrypted and to make a backup of the bitlocker keys first.

I confirmed the drive was indeed encrypted. Showing the lock, and manage-bde c: -status showed that it is indeed encrypted, though from explorer I can't change bitlocker.

I could not find the encryption keys in the personal account and nowhere else either. I decided to run manage-bde -off c: to turn off bitlocker, ran manage-bde -status c: enough times until it said the drive was no longer encrypted, then converted his account into a local account.

All went well so far, but then I wanted to activate bitlocker again, and now I'm getting the error (0x8031005a) Bitlocker is not supported, upgrade to windows 11 pro.

## Question

Since Bitlocker was previously enabled, it must be supported somehow. How can I activate bitlocker again?

See also: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/why-i-have-bitlocker-key-in-my-account-while-i/5b9c6924-318f-4064-8129-939f691b5330

Comment: It was impossible to have had BitLocker enabled on Windows 11 Home, it would have been device encryption that was enabled.

Comment: @Ramhound I think, based on how I got it solved, that you're right. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Windows 11 Home does come with Bitlocker, but its a lightweight version. You can't use the manage-bde to enable it, but you can search for bitlocker in the start menu, and from there turn the slider on to encrypt the drive again.

You have the official documentation here : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-on-device-encryption-0c453637-bc88-5f74-5105-741561aae838

Comment: It’s called Device Encryption. It’s specifically used on devices of certain form factors, specifically Tablets, as full disk encryption is required to be enabled by Microsoft on devices of that form factor

Answer (score -1):

You may use full bitlocker on Windows10 or 11 home using the following trick: Boot to the Windows recovery environment ("WinRE") or, alternatively, to windows setup. Open a command line (WinRE: go to troubleshooting ->advanced ->command line, Win Setup: Press Shift F10=. There: use Bitlocker pre-provisioning: `manage-bde -on c: -used`
Then reboot. Back in Windows, add the TPM and recovery password protectors on an elevated command prompt using `manage-bde -protectors -add c: -rp -tpm`
Take note of the recovery password (save it to a text file on your backup drive and print it). Afterwards: enable the protector: `manage-bde -protectors -enable c:`
Done! That's an excerpt of a full tutorial (by me) on https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33596/How-to-use-Bitlocker-on-Windows-10-Home.html

Comment: +1, good to know. In my case it would not have worked, as the device is a Microsoft Surface Pro and the customer was too far away and I only had remote support as option.